# summary() results consolidating to "(other)"

Tags: r

I'm attempting to use the `summary()` function like this: `summary(flights[c("carrier_code","carrier_name")])`, and my table comes out looking like this:

```
 1     :735559
 2     :551432
 3     :531577 
 4     :499418 
 5     :145080
 6     : 88908
 (Other):193873
```

What can i do to expand/get rid of the "(Other)" category that it generated in this frequency table so I can see the results for all the options?

Comment: Not reproducible as-is. For example `library(nycflights13); summary(flights[c("carrier","flight")])` returns a summary table as expected. If this snippet doesn't clarify what's going wrong for you, please provide a sample of the data you're working with that can reproduce your provided output.

Comment: You probably need to use `table()`  (or `dplyr::count()`) if you want to list the frequencies of all unique values (the variable you are summarizing here is presumably a factor ...)